# unset session in iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, iframe

I´m using an iFrame in a Webpage (Domain A). The content of the iFrame comes from another Webpage (Domain B) and shows up a ui-dialog for zipcode. After choosing the zipcode, the content of Domain B relods itself and saves the zipcode in a session. Domain A and Domain B are on the same Server. I want the session to be deleted whenever the page with the iFrame (Domain A) is reloaded.

I have already tried it with Get Variables in the URL of the iFrame (`www.mydomain.de?reloaded=yes`) but after choosing the zipcode, when the Domain B reloads, the sesion is deleted once more.

I just want to delete the session if Domain A is reloaded. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could apply that same strategy except use cURL to send the command, that way the query won't be left in your address bar. You might also try using a header to redirect and remove the query when you want to reset.

Comment: Did you try doing a redirect after unsetting the session value?

Comment: how should I do the redirect?

Comment: On domain 2, you should be able to do a script that does something like `...code to remove the session value; header('Location: http://www.blabla.de'); exit;`. Have it redirect to whatever the default address is.

Comment: Do you mean something like this on Domain B:

`if(isset($_GET['reloaded'])) {
 
unset($_SESSION['zip']);
session_destroy();

header('Location:http://www.bblablabla.de/online_order.php'); 
exit;

}`

but this doesent work. sessions are not deleted. and also this would be a kind of a loop doesen´t it?

Comment: Why do you say session wouldn't be deleted? That should delete the session, then redirect. If you are checking there is a `reload` key, there should be no loop since the redirect has no query with that key/value pair

Comment: Also, you don't need to `unset($_SESSION['zip']);`. `session_destroy();` will do that for you.

Comment: In the iFrame src of domain ababab.de/online_order.php I have:
`bababa.de?reload=yes`
this loads the page bababa.de and unsets the session and if I then use 
`if(isset($_GET['reloaded'])) { unset($_SESSION['zip']); session_destroy(); header('Location:http://www.ababab.de/online_order.php'); exit; }`
the first page will be loaded again and everything starts from new (if it would work). At the moment the content of the iFrame (bababa.de) is not loaded and i got a 404 in the iFrame.

Comment: ahhhrg i got it now :) thanks alot for your help bro. saved my day.

Comment: I would edit your answer below with what worked then mark it as answered so it will help others in the future.